# Module signing tries to use executing user instead of certificate user

Tags: sql-server, certificate, code-signing

I have a group of users that either do or don't have the correct access (from a different program) to get the results of a stored procedure.

I've created a view of individual user rights and which tables those rights can access. It was a whole process.

Then, I created the stored procedure in db1 that checks the rights of the calling user and performs a select query from db2 if they have the correct rights for all the tables as below.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPORT_COURSE_DELIVERY_METHOD_SP] 
    @pUSER NVARCHAR(15)
    
    
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @USER_RIGHTS table (REPL_ROLE NVARCHAR(10));
    DECLARE @TABLE_RIGHTS TABLE (TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(250), REPL_ROLE NVARCHAR(10));

    INSERT INTO @USER_RIGHTS
    EXEC db1.DBO.GET_USER_RIGHTS @pUSER;

    INSERT INTO @TABLE_RIGHTS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, [ROLE]
    FROM db1.DBO.VAL_TABLE_ROLE R
    WHERE R.TABLE_NAME IN ('CT_COU','VAL_COU_INSTR','VAL_COU_INSTR_UNIT');

    IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME) FROM @USER_RIGHTS U INNER JOIN @TABLE_RIGHTS T ON U.REPL_ROLE=T.REPL_ROLE)=3
        
        BEGIN 

        DECLARE @pYRTR INT = db1.DBO.CURR_FWDFLL_YRTR(); 
        DECLARE @pDATE INT = db1.DBO.GET_ISRS_DATE(); 

        SELECT C.YRTR, C.SUBJ, C.COU_NBR, C.SECT_NBR, C.TITLE, C.CRHR, C.COU_STAT, I.LONG_DESC INSTR_METHOD, U.LONG_DESC INSTR_SETTING
        FROM db2.DBO.CT_COU C 
            INNER JOIN db2.DBO.VAL_COU_INSTR I ON I.INSTR_TYPE = C.INSTR_TYPE 
            INNER JOIN db2.DBO.VAL_COU_INSTR_UNIT U ON U.INSTR_UNIT_TYPE = C.INSTR_UNIT_TYPE
        WHERE C.YRTR >= @pYRTR AND C.COU_STAT != 'C' AND C.END_DATE >= @pDATE
        ORDER BY C.YRTR, C.SUBJ, C.COU_NBR, C.SECT_NBR;

        END;

END
```

I've signed the stored procedure with a certificate with a private key from db1. I've countersigned db1.dbo.GET_USER_RIGHTS using the db1 certificate. I created the certificate in db2 without the private key. I created a user from the certificate that has select and execute on db1 and select on db2.

The code for the VS report is `EXEC db1.dbo.REPORT_COURSE_DELIVERY_METHOD_SP @pUSER` where `@pUSER` is defined as User!User.

The group of users has been given access to run REPORT_COURSE_DELIVERY_METHOD_SP.

The errors from the report server show that the calling user doesn't have access to db2, which is exactly the whole point of the module signing.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: *" I created a user from the certificate that has select and execute on db1 and select on db2."* Where did you create the `USER`? You can't `CREATE` a `USER` in `db2` that has `SELECT` on objects in `db1`; `USER`s are database objects.

Comment: @ThomA I tried to follow a tutorial... https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/cross-db-access-with-module-signing/. According to the image, it looks like you only create the user on db2, although I created a the same user on both databases from the certificate.

Comment: AFAICT, you shouldn't need to do anything with respect to `GET_USER_RIGHTS` in db1 and the certificate. That is, if my understanding is correct, your actual users (as contrasted with the certificate user) are in db1, and so long as `GET_USER_RIGHTS` references objects only in db1 only `EXECUTE` permission will need to be granted to those users. So, once you've signed the `REPORT_COURSE_DELIVERY_METHOD_SP` in db1, all that's left to do is create the cert-based user in db2 and grant it permissions on the tables it needs access to there. Posting the error message(s) you're getting will be useful.